# Mapserver and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, arcgis, mapserver

Anyone know how I can integrate Flex and Mapserver in much the same way Flex and ArcServer talk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Mapserver is WMS compliant, you should be able to use the [ModestMaps](http://modestmaps.com/) or [UMap](http://www.afcomponents.com/components/umap_as3/) libraries to display map tiles in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript API 1.3 for ArcGIS Server there are new ways to create custom classes for map handling on your own (i.e. integrate with WMS or whatever map format you use). I suppose similar possibilities will appear in new Flex API for AGS, too – if they're not there yet.

Of course, it's option only if you want (and may, for licensing reasons) to use ArcGIS Server API.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes. Each layer you put in a flex application from ArcGIS server is using Map Service url end point. There is always a wms url for the same service. What i suggest is that go replace the layer url with the WMS version from ArcGIS Server to test your FLEX application works on those layers then migrate services to MapServer.